# Upload a Zip file to nexus using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a SpringBoot app and as a part of the build, I want to zip together the generated fat jar, and some directories `conf` and `.sh` scripts from my source. Then upload that zip file to nexus. I am not able to achieve that.

Following are the tasks I have in my build.gradle

```
task myzip(type: Zip) {
    doFirst {
        new File(buildDir, 'logs').mkdirs()
    }
    def fileName = "${jar.baseName}-${jar.version}"
    from projectDir into 'manager-service'
    include "conf/*"
    include "*.sh"
    exclude "conf/config-client"
    from buildDir into 'manager-service'
    include "logs/*"
    from file("$buildDir/libs")
    include "${fileName}.jar"
    archiveName "manager-service.zip"
}

myzip.dependsOn(bootRepackage)

artifacts {archives myzip}
build.dependsOn(myzip)

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        apply plugin: 'maven'
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: System.getenv("NEXUSREPO")) {
                String username = System.getenv("NEXUS_SNAPSHOT_REPO_USERNAME");
                String password = System.getenv("NEXUS_SNAPSHOT_REPO_PASSWORD");
                print "foo"
                authentication(userName: username.toString(), password: password)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run the build, it fails with the following error:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:bootRepackage
\--- :myzip
     \--- :bootRepackage (*)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

With `myzip.dependsOn(bootRepackage)` your task "myZip" depends on the task "bootRepackage" which internally depends on the gradle tasks "assemble" and "build". This means "myZip" demands that "build", "assemble" and "bootRepackage" are executed first when you call "myZip".

`build.dependsOn(myzip)` means you make the task "build" depended on "myZip" to be executed in order to execute "build". This creates a loop.

To resolve this issue remove `build.dependsOn(myzip)` from your build.gradle file.